# Debian not booting 4.9.0-4 kernel after upgrading to stretch

Tags: linux, debian, boot

yesterday I upgraded a debian jessie to stretch. I had installed all updates before changing the sources.list to this:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

The upgrade went smoothly, but I am not able to boot kernel 4.9.0-4. After a couple of minutes waiting I get these messages:

[image]

However I can still boot kernel 3.16.0-4-686-pae which remained installed.

I'm not really sure where I am supposed to start looking for the cause. Does anybody have an idea on how to start investigating?

Btw: The computer is a vm running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with the HyperV role (all current updates are installed).

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling using `apt-get install  --reinstall linux-image-4.9.0-7-amd64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems this was an issue with only this particular kernel. After installing 4.13.0-0.bpo.1-686-pae it would boot from that automatically. No further changes on the system were required to fix it.